# How can we create two things in the tool bar (ex: create and search) in grid kendo ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-grid

I try to create Search box and Create in the toolbar but it doesnot work. Tool bar only accept 1 of them.
Any one can help me

Comment: Can you show the code that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The [toolbar-template](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/toolbar-template) example shows how to customize your toolbar. The example demonstrates adding a refresh icon and a search box.

You can also add a search box after the grid is configured.

```
    $('#myGridID .k-grid-toolbar').append(
        '<form id="searchForm" action="#">'
        + '<input class="k-textbox k-space-right" type="search" id="searchTerm" placeholder="Search term..."/><span title="Find by Name or Address" id="searchGo" class="k-icon k-i-search"></span>'
        + '</form>'
    );
    $("#searchForm").submit(onSearchSubmit)
    $("#searchGo").click(onSearchSubmit);
```

and set the grid filter accordingly

```
function onSearchSubmit(e) {
    var term, grid, criteria;

    e.preventDefault();

    term = $("#searchTerm").val();
    grid = $("#myGridID").data("kendoGrid");
    criteria = {
        logic: "or",
        filters: [
            { field: "Name", operator: "contains", value: term },
            { field: "Address", operator: "contains", value: term }
    ]};
    if (term === "") { criteria = null } // no criteria, show all records
    grid.dataSource.filter(criteria);
}
```